# Android ListView - Assigning Intents to Strings in a Listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, onclick, android-listview

I have a ListView of football team names, which are added to a listview using the code below.

```
public final String[] teamnames = { "Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Man United" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,teamnames);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I need some help with the onListItemClick method.

For each football team in the listview, I would like to assign an intent to it. So Arsenal would open a class activity called ars.java.

This needs to be done for 20 teams.

If I set up an array of Classnames, how can I iterate through the listview and assign the corresponding classname to each teamname?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Barak So when a user clicks on a teamname in the listview, it takes them to an activity for that team.

Comment: But why would you have activities for every team?

Comment: Are each of your team classes all that different?  I might suggest using one "team" class and pass in the team name that was selected using the putExtra() function when you create the intent.  Having a class for each team seems like you might be duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: That's where I was heading with my question.  :)

Comment: @ScottNaef I'm a novice coder, there are a lot of functions I am unaware of. Can you provide me with an example for putExtra() please?

Comment: I think the two examples below should get you going.   Take a look a the lifecycle for the Activity class.  [This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) should provide a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put in an extra when you set up the intent (before you start the activity) like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, TeamActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("TeamName", teamname);
ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then you retrieve it in the activity you called like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String team = extras.getString("TeamName");
```

That puts your team name into the `team`string variable for you to use as necessary.

Comment: Thank you explaining this concept to me. Going to give both these answers a try.

Comment: Does the first snippet of code go in the onListItemClick() method?

Comment: Yes, that is where it should go.  Note I had an error (I used one of my classnames instead of yours, I've corrected that now).

Comment: I get the following error when running my app: Key TeamName expected String but value was a [Ljava.lang.String;.  The default value <null> was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I recommend using `intent.putExtra` as well
Here's an example implementation:

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        teamName = teamNames[position]; // Assuming the order is the same
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), ShowDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("team", teamName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The `ShowDetail.class` is the activity that you want to launch which passes an extra that has the team name inside.
To get the name of the team in `ShowDetail`, you can call

```
    String team = getIntent().getStringExtra("team");
```

in the `onCreate` method.